# ID de un elemento igual a la vuelta del bucle for

Tags: javascript, bucles

Debo realizar este código 6 veces más cambiando el número de cada id, por ejemplo `cantidadproduct-1` que cambie a `cantidadproduct-2` y así sucesivamente hasta 6. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con un bucle `for`? Todo esto en JS y jQuery.

Necesito también cambiar todas las variables que se encuentran numeradas (deben llegar hasta el 6). Estoy haciendo como un carrito de compra y tengo 6 productos, y necesito que ese código se aplique para cada producto. Por eso cada variable e Id posee un número.

Éste es el código:

```
var cantidadproduct1 = 0;
$('#btn-1').click(function() {

    //SE ACTUALIZA EL TOTAL
    total = total + parseInt($('#product1-price').text());
    $('#total').text(total);

    //SI ES LA PRIMERA VEZ QUE SE AGREGA EL PRODUCTO, SE ESCRIBE LA CANTIDAD "1", EN CAMBIO, SI YA SÉ AGREGÓ ANTERIORMENTE SOLAMENTE SE CAMBIA LA CANTIDAD EN EL CARRITO Y NO SE AGREGA OTRO <LI>.
    if (cantidadproduct1 == 0) {
        cantidadproduct1++;
        $('.cart-ul').append('<li id="product1-oncart" class="row justify-content-between item-inside-cart align-items-center mb-2"><span>' + ($('#product1-name').text()) + '</span><span>' + ($('#product1-price').text()) + '</span><span id="item-quantity-1" class="item-quantity d-block ml-3">x' + cantidadproduct1 + '</span><a href="#" id="delete-item-1" class="delete-item"><img class="delete-img" src="materiales/img/basura.png" alt="trash bin icon" tooltip="eliminar producto"></a></li>');
        var img1 = $("#item1-image").children("img").clone();
        $('#product1-oncart').prepend(img1);
        $('#total').text(total);

    } else if (cantidadproduct1 > 0) {
        cantidadproduct1++;
        $('#item-quantity-1').text('x' + cantidadproduct1);
    }


    //SI SE TOCA EL TACHO DE BASURA SE ELMINA EL RESPECTIVO PRODUCTO.--------------------
    $('#delete-item-1').unbind('click').click(function() {

        //SE RESTA LA CANTIDAD DEL PRODUCTO Y LA CANTIDAD GLOBAL.
        cantidadproduct1--;
        cantidad--;

        //SE ACTUALIZA EL INDICADOR DE ELEMENTOS EN EL CARRITO
        $('#cart-indicator').text(cantidad);
        $('#item-quantity-1').text('x' + cantidadproduct1);
        total = total - parseInt($('#product1-price').text());

        if(cantidadproduct1 == 0){
            $('#product1-oncart').remove();
        }

        $('#total').text(total);

        //SI NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN EL CARRITO APARECE UNA ILUSTRACIÓN --------
        if (cantidad == 0) {

            $('.empty-container').addClass('d-block');
            $('.empty-container').removeClass('d-none');
            $('.cart-buy').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');

        }

    });
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a `item-quantity-1` o `product1-oncart` o `item1-image`? Hay muchas variables con número en el código.

Comment: Exacto, necesito que cada una de esas variables que tengan un "1", vayan cambiando hasta el número 6.

Comment: ¿Y la variable `cantidadproducto1`? ¿Realmente no importa que sea numerada? Parece que es algo auxiliar

Comment: Todas las que se encuentran numeradas deben llegar hasta el 6, es que estoy haciendo como un carrito de compra y tengo 6 productos, y necesito que ese código se aplique para cada producto. Por eso cada variable e Id posee un número.

Comment: Ok. Como comentario aparte, ¿has pensado en usar un array para guardar esos valores? Simplificaría mucho el código y lo dejaría más ordenado

Comment: Emm sinceramente no tengo idea, soy muy principiante con esto y me asignaron este trabajo y bueno, lo hice como pude jaja. Me podrías explicar en que ayudaría? Mil gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo estás guardando la información de los 6 productos del carrito?

Comment: Tengo un array que posee todos los productos, que en total con 15. El tema es que yo quiero aplicar esa función solamente a 6...

Answer (score 1):

La idea es básicamente envolver tu código en un bucle `for` que vaya de 1 a 6 (incluidos), luego en los selectores cambiar el `1` por el valor de la variable que estés usando. Esto lo puedes hacer varios modos, pero los dos más sencillos:

1. Concatenando la variable a la cadena: `"cadena" + variable + "cadena"`
2. Usando literales de plantilla: `` `cadena${variable}cadena` ``

Esto aplicado a tu código:

```
for (x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {

    var cantidadproduct1 = 0;
    $('#btn-'+x).click(function() {

        //SE ACTUALIZA EL TOTAL
        total = total + parseInt($('#product'+x+'-price').text());
        $('#total').text(total);

        //SI ES LA PRIMERA VEZ QUE SE AGREGA EL PRODUCTO, SE ESCRIBE LA CANTIDAD "1", EN CAMBIO, SI YA SÉ AGREGÓ ANTERIORMENTE SOLAMENTE SE CAMBIA LA CANTIDAD EN EL CARRITO Y NO SE AGREGA OTRO <LI>.
        if (cantidadproduct1 == 0) {
            cantidadproduct1++;
            $('.cart-ul').append('<li id="product'+x+'-oncart" class="row justify-content-between item-inside-cart align-items-center mb-2"><span>' + ($('#product'+x+'-name').text()) + '</span><span>' + ($('#product'+x+'-price').text()) + '</span><span id="item-quantity-1" class="item-quantity d-block ml-3">x' + cantidadproduct1 + '</span><a href="#" id="delete-item-'+x+'" class="delete-item"><img class="delete-img" src="materiales/img/basura.png" alt="trash bin icon" tooltip="eliminar producto"></a></li>');
            var img1 = $("#item'+x+'-image").children("img").clone();
            $('#product'+x+'-oncart').prepend(img1);
            $('#total').text(total);

        } else if (cantidadproduct1 > 0) {
            cantidadproduct1++;
            $('#item-quantity-'+x).text('x' + cantidadproduct1);
        }


        //SI SE TOCA EL TACHO DE BASURA SE ELMINA EL RESPECTIVO PRODUCTO.--------------------
        $('#delete-item-'+x).unbind('click').click(function() {

            //SE RESTA LA CANTIDAD DEL PRODUCTO Y LA CANTIDAD GLOBAL.
            cantidadproduct1--;
            cantidad--;

            //SE ACTUALIZA EL INDICADOR DE ELEMENTOS EN EL CARRITO
            $('#cart-indicator').text(cantidad);
            $('#item-quantity-'+x).text('x' + cantidadproduct1);
            total = total - parseInt($('#product'+x+'-price').text());

            if(cantidadproduct1 == 0){
                $('#product'+x+'-oncart').remove();
            }

            $('#total').text(total);

            //SI NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN EL CARRITO APARECE UNA ILUSTRACIÓN --------
            if (cantidad == 0) {

                $('.empty-container').addClass('d-block');
                $('.empty-container').removeClass('d-none');
                $('.cart-buy').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');

            }

        });

    }); 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero como puedo aplicarlo a las demás variables como cantidadproduct1?

Comment: O sea, puedo aplicarlo también a las variables como img1 y cantidadproduct-1? Porque en el código que me enviaste no están cambiadas, es por alguna razón? Desde mil gracias, en serio.

Comment: @TobíasCorradi para eso te recomendaría tener un array (p.e. `img` o `cantidadproduct`)

Comment: No hay ninguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Y si los tuviera que hacer en un array cómo sería?